# The new dotty runtime totally dies on me

Tags: scala, dotty, scala-3

Saturday morning here. Trying to learn the new Scala compiler dotty.

Installed in on my Mac using

```
brew install lampepfl/brew/dotty
```

Installation was successful. I got version

```
dotr -version
Starting dotty REPL...
Dotty compiler version 0.20.0-RC1 -- Copyright 2002-2019, LAMP/EPFL
```

created directory

```
mkdir dotty
```

wrote this code in `Hello.scala`

```
import Console._
@main def foo(s: String) : Unit =
 println(s"Hello $s")
```

I was able to compile it

```
dotc Hello.scala
```

Got a bunch of `.class` and `.tasty` files

Next I did

```
dotr
:load Hello.scala
```

Now I get this massive "explosion" of an error and the dotr runtime totally dies and exits.

What did I do to cause this explosion? This isn't a friendly error message.

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: PackageDef(Ident(<empty>),List(ValDef(rs$line$1,Ident(rs$line$1$),
Apply(Select(New(Ident(rs$line$1$)),<init>),List())), TypeDef(rs$line$1$,Template(DefDef(<init>,List(),List(List()),
TypeTree[TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class scala)),class Unit)],EmptyTree),List(Apply(Select(New(
TypeTree[TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class lang)),class Object)]),<init>),List()), Select(Select(
Ident(_root_),scala),Serializable)),ValDef(_,SingletonTypeTree(Ident(rs$line$1)),EmptyTree),List(Import(Ident(Console),
List(ImportSelector(Ident(_),EmptyTree,EmptyTree))),DefDef(foo,List(),List(List(ValDef(s,Ident(String),EmptyTree))),
Ident(Unit),Apply(Ident(println),List(Apply(Select(Apply(Select(Select(Select(Ident(_root_),scala),StringContext),apply),
List(Typed(SeqLiteral(List(Literal(Constant(hello )), Literal(Constant())),TypeTree[TypeRef(TermRef(
ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class scala)),module Predef),type String)]),
TypeTree[AppliedType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class scala)),class <repeated>),
List(TypeRef(TermRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class scala)),module Predef),type String)))]))),s),
List(Typed(SeqLiteral(List(Ident(s)),TypeTree[TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class scala)),class Any)]),
TypeTree[AppliedType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class scala)),class <repeated>),

List(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class scala)),class Any)))]))))))))), TypeDef(foo,Template(DefDef(<init>,List(),List(List()),TypeTree[TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class scala)),class Unit)],EmptyTree),List(Apply(Select(New(TypeTree[TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class lang)),class Object)]),<init>),List())),ValDef(_,EmptyTree,EmptyTree),List(DefDef(main,List(),List(List(ValDef(args,TypeTree[AppliedType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class scala)),class Array),List(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class lang)),class String)))],EmptyTree))),TypeTree[TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class scala)),class Unit)],Try(Apply(Ident(foo),List(Apply(Apply(TypeApply(Ident(parseArgument),List(TypeTree[TypeRef(TermRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class scala)),module Predef),type String)])),List(Ident(args), Literal(Constant(0)))),List(Ident(given_FromString_String))))),List(CaseDef(Bind(error,Typed(Ident(_),TypeTree[TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(ThisType(TypeRef(NoPrefix,module class util)),module class CommandLineParser$)),class ParseError)])),EmptyTree,Apply(Ident(showError),List(Ident(error))))),EmptyTree))))))) (of class dotty.tools.dotc.ast.Trees$PackageDef)
    at dotty.tools.repl.CollectTopLevelImports.topLevelImports$1(CollectTopLevelImports.scala:23)
    at dotty.tools.repl.CollectTopLevelImports.run(CollectTopLevelImports.scala:28)
    at dotty.tools.dotc.core.Phases$Phase.runOn$$anonfun$1(Phases.scala:315)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:219)
    at dotty.tools.dotc.core.Phases$Phase.runOn(Phases.scala:316)
    at dotty.tools.dotc.Run.runPhases$4$$anonfun$4(Run.scala:162)
    at dotty.runtime.function.JProcedure1.apply(JProcedure1.java:15)
    at dotty.runtime.function.JProcedure1.apply(JProcedure1.java:10)
    at scala.collection.ArrayOps$.foreach$extension(ArrayOps.scala:1323)
    at dotty.tools.dotc.Run.runPhases$5(Run.scala:172)
    at dotty.tools.dotc.Run.compileUnits$$anonfun$1(Run.scala:180)
    at dotty.runtime.function.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
    at dotty.tools.dotc.util.Stats$.maybeMonitored(Stats.scala:65)
    at dotty.tools.dotc.Run.compileUnits(Run.scala:187)
    at dotty.tools.dotc.Run.compileUnits(Run.scala:129)
    at dotty.tools.repl.ReplCompiler.runCompilationUnit(ReplCompiler.scala:156)
    at dotty.tools.repl.ReplCompiler.compile(ReplCompiler.scala:166)
    at dotty.tools.repl.ReplDriver.compile(ReplDriver.scala:227)
    at dotty.tools.repl.ReplDriver.interpret(ReplDriver.scala:193)
    at dotty.tools.repl.ReplDriver.run$$anonfun$1(ReplDriver.scala:136)
    at dotty.tools.repl.ReplDriver.withRedirectedOutput(ReplDriver.scala:148)
    at dotty.tools.repl.ReplDriver.run(ReplDriver.scala:137)
    at dotty.tools.repl.ReplDriver.interpretCommand(ReplDriver.scala:345)
    at dotty.tools.repl.ReplDriver.interpret(ReplDriver.scala:200)
    at dotty.tools.repl.ReplDriver.loop$1(ReplDriver.scala:127)
    at dotty.tools.repl.ReplDriver.runUntilQuit$$anonfun$1(ReplDriver.scala:130)
    at dotty.tools.repl.ReplDriver.withRedirectedOutput(ReplDriver.scala:148)
    at dotty.tools.repl.ReplDriver.runUntilQuit(ReplDriver.scala:130)
    at dotty.tools.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:6)
    at dotty.tools.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
```

Comment: What is your version of Dotty? Try the latest version with `sbt new ...` http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/usage/getting-started.html

Comment: Dotty compiler version 0.20.0-RC1

Comment: Did you try `sbt compile`, `sbt run`, `sbt console`?

Comment: is SBT a necessity? can't I work just with the compiler and repl?

Comment: Fixed in 0.21. There were "how do I invoke my code" gotchas in Scala 2, I hope the story is smoother in Scala 3.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify program argument

```
$ dotr foo
Illegal command line: more arguments expected

$ dotr foo World
Hello World
```

Just `dotr` runs REPL. In REPL `:load <path>` means "interpret lines in a file". How is `dotr` supposed to get program argument?

Comment: My expectation was that first I will do `:load Hello.scala` and then when its loaded call `foo "Hello"`

Comment: I am able to do it via `dotr foo "Foo"` as well but how do I `:load` my code and then run it?

Comment: It can't be just `foo "Hello"` because `@main` generates `final class foo {
  <static> def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = ...` http://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/main-functions.html It seems `@main` doesn't compile in REPL. This can be a bug. Bugs should be reported here https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues

Comment: You can avoid `@main` in REPL. You can write `object foo {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(s"Hello ${args(0)}")
  }
}` and call it `foo.main(Array("World"))` or write `def foo(s: String) : Unit =
  println(s"Hello $s")` and call it `foo("World")`.

Comment: The solution you gave above doesn't work with spaces. Try `dotr foo "Foo Bar"` it only prints foo. Also. I logged an issue https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/7529 because DOTR should not crash upon encountering `@main`

Comment: I guess in order to work with `Foo Bar` the function should be `@main def foo(s: String, s1: String) : Unit =
println(s"Hello $s $s1")`
or
`@main def foo(s: String*) : Unit =
  println(s.fold("Hello")(_ + " " + _))`.